# How to add a custom language REPL to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, r, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 (and 2015) now features a `REPL` for interactive `C#, F#, R, Python` and possibly others.  `View -> Other Windows ->` and whatever is installed should be visible.

[image: C# Interactive menu item]

[image: C# REPL]

Suppose I wanted to integrate my own (existing domain-specific) language into Visual Studio such that its `REPL` would be started by clicking on a menu item in Other Windows.  I am only interested in using Visual Studio's built-in `REPL` services to conduct a dialogue with an existing language - not to design a language nor to use any of the `DSM` facilities provided by .Net or Microsoft.  At least today.

**Where would I begin?**  Would the Interactive R implementation be a suitable starting point?  (The R interpreter would resemble my DSM more closely than say C#)

The appeal here is Visual Studio integration and the ability to reuse existing components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on limited information on your DSL it is necessary to make assumption which equally well may be treated as requirements:

1. There is a compiler for DSL which is capable to produce partial syntax trees and compiles them to partial binaries, 'method bodies' or there is a compiler based expression evaluator.
2. There is a runtime on which DSL can be executed even as partial binaries (if the result of a compilation is an intermediate language then you would need virtual machine otherwise system specific runtime library).
3. There is a lot of work to do the plumbing between input/output interactive window, runtime, compiler between themselves and Visual Studio.

There are several examples which can be analyzed for prior art:

Roslyn Compiler

Scripting https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Scripting

Interactive Services https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/VisualStudio/InteractiveServices

One which could be of direct use in REPL project is:

ReplHTML project https://github.com/TiarkRompf/replhtml

There are many toolkits available for fast development of a DSL or in principle for development of any programming language. Check some papers by Tiark Rompf  as he was and is working on cross language virtual machines and efficient DSL/programming language development based on Graal VM. He is currently at Purdue University but before that he was working with Martin Odersky at EPFL in Switzeralnd on Scala, programming language development frameworks and their integration with virtual machines.

I would discourage you in using anything R as this is one of the examples from which one should not learn how to work with or develop programming languages.

Final warning: this is a big project which may require much more than one engineer year to complete successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer.  As such, I'm interested only in integrating an existing language into VS and learning how to use the REPL-related services as provided by VS.  I've hopefully improved my question at least slightly.  I have poked around a bit at the Roslyn stuff on GitHub but frankly find the RTVS package a bit more promising as it is at least considerably smaller.  As such, I agree with your comment about the R language itself (I used S heavily in a previous life), but have still to discover whether its interface to the VS REPL services is worth it.